ubuntu 24.04 gnome terminal 3.52.0 always scrolls down on output
Before Ubuntu 24.04 I could scroll up in my terminal while it was, for example, running an apt-update. The view would just remain where I was and only if I pressed a key (or if I turned on scrolling on output), it would scroll to the bottom.
Since Ubuntu 24.04, the terminal keeps scrolling to the bottom whenever a process is printing something (also those that do not strictly 'add' lines such as those with ascii progress spinners). I have verified that scrolling on output is turned off. It also sometimes scrolls down when I try to click or highlight some text in the terminal.

it is possible to turn off this behaviour in the settings: Scroll on keystroke. But this means you will have to manually scroll when you start typing something.
